# Order infinite or finite

Tags: group-theory

If $b$ has infinite order and $a$ has finite order what is the order of $bab^{-1}$?

Sorry for the formatting. I'm using the app.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a\mapsto bab^{-1}$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Can you show that $a^k=1$ if and only if $(bab^{-1})^k=1$? This leads to the result in Nicky Hekster's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: two elements that are conjugate have the same order, so $a$ and $bab^{-1}$ have the same order. The order of $b$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is the order of b irrelevant?

Comment: Nvmd just figured it out

Comment: Ok great! Then you actually learned something, which is better than me providing the answer right away!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Since $a$ has a finite order, let $\textrm{ord}(a) = n$. What happens if you raise your conjugated element to the $n^{th}$ power?

$$(bab^{-1})^n =\ ?$$

Comment: (b^n)a^n(b^-1)^n = (b^n)e(b^-1)^n =e

Comment: @user277658 your calculation is incorrect.

Comment: @MattSamuel Can you please explain why?

Comment: Your calculation is correct - see how it means that $(bab^{-1})$ has a finite order? (proving that the order is exactly $n$ requires a tiny bit more work, but it's not necessary)

Comment: @user277658 it's the beginning that's wrong. You got the right end result. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A misunderstanding you seem to have (sorry if I'm wrong) is that you seem to think exponents distribute over products. This is not true unless the group is abelian. So for example
$$(bab^{-1})^n\neq b^na^nb^{-n}$$
However, in this case the exponent does distribute, but it's an accident. It's because you get the identity either way.

An equation is worth a thousand words:
$$(bab^{-1})^2=bab^{-1}bab^{-1}=baab^{-1}=ba^{2}b^{-1}$$
I'm sure you see that if you keep doing this the exponent of $a$ is the only thing that changes. This explains why an element has the same order as its conjugates.

Comment: Oh ok. So algebraically it would be: (bab^-1)^n = (bab^-1)(bab^-1)....(bab^-1) = (a)(a)...(a)=a^n=e

Comment: No, it's $ba^{n}b^{-1}=beb^{-1}=bb^{-1}=e$.

Comment: Oh yeah, damn tiny keys on phone.